# Remove string between two variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, replace

I have a string which has some data with a few special characters, Need to remove the data between the desired special char in JavaScript.

The special char would be obtained in a variable.

```
var desiredChar = "~0~";
```

And Imagine this to be the Input string:

**~0~1|0|20170807|45|111.00|~0~**~1~1|0|20170807|50|666.00|~1~~2~1|0|20170807|55|111.00|~2~

So I'm supposed to remove the text in bold.

The desired output is supposed to be-

~1~1|0|20170807|50|666.00|~1~~2~1|0|20170807|55|111.00|~2~

I've tried using "Replace" and "Regex", but as the desired character is being passed in a variable and keeps changing I'm facing difficulties.

Comment: In the example I've considered its ~0~. But it can be anything like ~1~ or ~2~. So need to consider the variable as a whole

Comment: Is it always at beginning of string?

Comment: No, not necessarily the beginning, it can be anywhere..

Comment: _I've tried using "Replace" and "Regex"_ - it is good to show what you have tried here, so that readers can differentiate your posts from questions that have had no prior attempt at all.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs @halfer..Will try to follow the same even in future..:)..Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own regex based on whatever the bounding character(s) are that contain the text you want removed, and then replace any text that matches that regex with a blank string `""`.

The JS below should work for your use case (and it should work for multiple occurrences as well):

```js
var originalText = "~0~1|0|20170807|45|111.00|~0~~1~1|0|20170807|50|666.00|~1~~2~1|0|20170807|55|111.00|~2~";

var desiredChar = "~0~";
var customRegex = new RegExp(desiredChar + ".*?" + desiredChar, "gi");

var processedText = originalText.replace(customRegex, "");
console.log(processedText);
```

Comment: Thanks a ton @abagshaw ..This works perfectly..Saved me

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Given input string you can use `.indexOf()`, `.lastIndexOf()` and `.slice()`.

Note, OR character `|` passed to `RegExp` constructor should be escaped to avoid `RegExp` created by passing string interpreting `|` character as `OR` `|` within resulting `RegExp` passed to `.replace()`.

```js
var desiredChar = "~0~";

var str = "~0~1|0|20170807|45|111.00|~0~~1~1|0|20170807|50|666.00|~1~~2~1|0|20170807|55|111.00|~2~";

var not = str.slice(str.indexOf(desiredChar), str.lastIndexOf(desiredChar) + desiredChar.length);
// escape OR `|`
var res = str.replace(new RegExp(not.replace(/[|]/g, "\\|")), "");

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build your regex from the constructor with a string input.

```
var desiredChar = "~0~";
// use the g flag in your regex if you want to remove all substrings between desiredChar
var myRegex = new Regex(desiredChar + ".*" + desiredChar, 'ig');

var testString = "~0~1|0|20170807|45|111.00|~0~~1~1|0|20170807|50|666.00|~1~~2~1|0|20170807|55|111.00|~2~";
testString = testString.replace(myRegex, "");
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the RegExp object:

```
var regexstring = "whatever";
var regexp = new RegExp(regexstring, "gi");
var str = "whateverTest";
var str2 = str.replace(regexp, "other");
document.write(str2);
```

Then you can construct regexstring in any way you want.

You can read more about it at http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html